# Using FileChangedReloadingStrategy and it's alternatives

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-commons

To dynamically reload my app configuration, I decided to try out Apache commons 
[FileChangedReloadingStrategy](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/javadocs/v1.10/apidocs/org/apache/commons/configuration/reloading/FileChangedReloadingStrategy.html)

I am doing Ldap Authentication using Spring Security and before using `FileChangedReloadingStrategy`, I was keeping a single instance of `LdapTemplate`, like:

```
@Component
public class LdapAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider{  


    private LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;  
    private LdapContextSource contextSource;    

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {        
        contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(LDAP_CONFIG_BASE_URL);
        contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(LDAP_CONFIG_IS_ANONYMOUS);
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);
    }   

@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
// use ldapTemplate to do authentication
}
```

However, since now I am trying to provide a dynamic config change, I have to create a new ldap connection each time (so that modified config,if any, could be used). But this will affect performance.

```
@Autowired
private AppConfig config;

@Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        contextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        contextSource.setUrl(config.getProperty("LDAP_CONFIG_BASE_URL"));
        contextSource.setAnonymousReadOnly(Boolean.parseBoolean(config.getProperty("LDAP_CONFIG_IS_ANONYMOUS")));
        contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(contextSource);

            // Do auth related stuff
}
```

So my question is, can this trade off between performance and providing dynamic config be avoided? Is there a non-Springboot way to refresh beans?

**NOTE:**: I found out that with Springboot, you can use Spring-cloud in which there is way to refresh beans but I am not using Springboot and could not find proper documentation to use  spring-cloud without Springboot so I stuck to Apache's FileChangedReloadingStrategy.

**EDIT:**
I am facing the performance issue in which ldap connection pool sometimes becomes full and I get connection time out error due to this.

Comment: You don't do performance optimization by guessing. If you can't demonstrate you have performance issues, don't try to solve problems you don't have.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about trying to solve a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: @Kayaman I am facing the performance issue in which ldap connection pool sometimes becomes full and I get connection time out error due to this.

Comment: Then why is your question not  about a connection pool becoming full? Why did you write about "guessing" that`FileChangedReloadingStrategy` affects performance? If your question is really about evicting connections from a pool, you wrote a lot of irrelevant things.

Comment: If you read the question details, I am trying to find a solution(maybe alternative to using `FileChangedReloadingStrategy`). I will edit question headline

Comment: You should show the settings for your pool, if that's what the actual problem is. So far you haven't really managed to describe your real problem.

Comment: @Kayaman Connection issue doesn't come if I use single LdapTemplate instance. But if I construct a new instance each time in Authenticate method, it has come randomly a few times. Irrespective of that, I still want to know: whether my approach towards using `FileChangedReloadingStrategy` is correct. And if there is some alternative to using `FileChangedReloadingStrategy` such that I construct a new LdapTemplate instance only when there is a config change.